# How do I change my DOCTYPE to HTML5?

Tags: template, html

I need to change my DOCTYPE to HTML5 from `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

This is a requirement of Google in order to be approved as a Google Trusted Store.

Can anyone advise **how I do this and if there are any downsides to it?**

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the doctype in the following files:

- `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme/page/1column.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme/page/2columns-left.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme/page/2columns-right.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme/page/3columns.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme/page/empty.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme/page/popup.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme/page/print.phtml`

In those files, replace the following line at the top of the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

With:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Regarding any downside, I'm afraid this is not Magento related so I suggest you check this very good StackOverflow post regarding [reasons not to start using html 5 doctype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629/any-reason-not-to-start-using-the-html-5-doctype)

Comment: Thanks. Are there any downsides or potential adverse effects in doing this Raphel?

Comment: @Jimnibob see my updated answer

Comment: Anyone looking for a Magento 2 solution, override `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme/templates/root.phtml` from `magento-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml` to edit the doctype